# AWS Glue : java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support binary data type

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, aws-glue

I'm trying to implement upsert with `aws glue` and `databricks` using `preactions` and `postactions`, Here is the code below

```
sample_dataframe.write.format("com.databricks.spark.redshift")\
  .option("url", "jdbc:redshift://staging-db.asdf.ap-southeast-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/stagingdb?user=sample&password=pwd")\
  .option("preactions", PRE_ACTION)\
  .option("postactions", POST_ACTION)\
  .option("dbtable", temporary_table)\
  .option("extracopyoptions", "region 'ap-southeast-1'")\
  .option("aws_iam_role", "arn:aws:iam::1234:role/AWSService-Role-ForRedshift-etl-s3")\
  .option("tempdir", args["TempDir"])\
  .mode("append")\
  .save()
```

I'm getting the following error

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o90.save.
: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: CSV data source does not support binary data type.
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$datasources$csv$CSVUtils$$verifyType$1(CSVUtils.scala:127)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.csv.CSVUtils$$anonfun$verifySchema$1.apply(CSVUtils.scala:131)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
```

Maybe I've missed something. Please help TIA.

I've also tried passing `preactions` and `postactions` as connection_options (below) and this too doesn't seem to work

```
redshift_datasink = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_jdbc_conf(frame = sample_dyn_frame, catalog_connection='Staging' , connection_options = connect_options, redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], transformation_ctx = "redshift_datasink")
```

Comment: What's the schema of your `sample_dataframe` ?

Comment: `root
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
|-- updated_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- updated_by: string (nullable = true)
|-- created_at: timestamp (nullable = true)
|-- deleted: boolean (nullable = true)
|-- id: long (nullable = true)
|-- region: string (nullable = true)
|-- name: string (nullable = true)
|-- created_by: string (nullable = true)`
Some fields are null, not sure if it for because of that.